# Representing "My" in Logo Design

Tags: logo, symbolism

What's a good way to represent "My" or ownership in a logo? Specifically own ideas.

[Edit:] The logo is for a web app called [Mypothesis](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=mypothesis), it's for people to put their own personal theories out there, it's meant to be scientific in context.
[Edit 2:] The reason why I want to represent "My" is because it's what separates Mypothesis from hypothesis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A graphic of a head with a thought bubble thinking of:

- a light bulb (incandescent or CFL)
- scientific notation (sigma, E=mc<sup>2</sup>)
- a graph of a formula (sine wave)
- an algebraic kind of formula (X=y<sup>2</sup> + z)